# itemDescription not showing for HtmlSelectManyCheckbox

Tags: java, jsf

In JSF, I have an HtmlSelectManyCheckbox, defined like this:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox required="true">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="cats" 
        itemDescription="Description not displayed"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="dogs"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="birds"/>
 ...
```

When the page is rendered, I can't see the itemDescription.
Is this a known behavior with JSF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Facelet Taglib Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/index.html):

`itemLabel`: Label to be displayed to the user for this option.

`itemDescription`: Description of this option, for use in development tools.

I understand this as the itemLabel is the displayed attribute.